# Symfony 2.0 FOSUserBundle with OpenID

Tags: symfony, openid, fosuserbundle

I tried to integrate FOSUserBundle with FpOpenIDBundle but I encountered a problem when auth is proccesed.
I get error

> Instances of "Alef\UserBundle\Entity\User" are not supported.

My class looks like this

```
<?php

namespace Alef\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


 /**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table( name="alef_users" )
 * 
 * @author James Morris <james@jmoz.co.uk>
 * @package SecurityBundle
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements \FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Alef\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="alef_user_groups",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="facebookId", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $facebookId;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->facebookId, parent::serialize()));;
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        list($this->facebookId, $parentData) = unserialize($data);
        parent::unserialize($parentData);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $firstname
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $lastname
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Get the full name of the user (first + last name)
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastname();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $facebookId
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFacebookId($facebookId)
    {
        $this->facebookId = $facebookId;
        $this->setUsername($facebookId);
        $this->salt = '';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFacebookId()
    {
        return $this->facebookId;
    }

    /**
     * @param Array
     */
    public function setFBData($fbdata)
    {
        if (isset($fbdata['id'])) {
            $this->setFacebookId($fbdata['id']);
            $this->addRole('ROLE_FACEBOOK');
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['first_name'])) {
            $this->setFirstname($fbdata['first_name']);
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['last_name'])) {
            $this->setLastname($fbdata['last_name']);
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['email'])) {
            $this->setEmail($fbdata['email']);
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->facebookId = 0;
    }

}
```

I know it's inheritance problem because FpOpenId inherits original symfony security user class but FOSUSer doesn't inherit from it. Is there any way to update FPOpenIDBundle to actually work with it?

Comment: Notice: Don't use fpOpenID anymore if you want to keep your sanity. It's not been updated for a year and it'll break on current PHP/Symfony2 versions because vital methods like getExtraInformation() have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Mine configuration looks like this:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface as SecurityUserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
}
```

I was overwriting the entire class because of the hyper custom features.

Just add

```
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
```

Regards,
Max

Comment: Wait what? You rewrote entire FoS User class?

Comment: The FoS-User-class is not _that_ special (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php). It's even mentioned in the FoSUserBundle-docs, that you _can_ (but not _have to_) extend the `User`-class

Comment: Which user class? As you can see i extend `User` class but FOS User class. But it's not enough. It needs to be Symfony user class.

Comment: But BaseUser(from FOS) class extends the symfony user class

Answer (score 0):

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function addGroup(GroupInterface $group)
    {
        parent::addGroup($group);
    }
}
```